# Include text from other files in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to create email templates for my website.

#### My template

So let's say this is my `template_header.php`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            '.$email_subject.'
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

And this is my `template_footer.php`:

```
    </body>
</html>
```

#### The problem

As I know I can use output buffering to include these templates.
This is my code:

```php
<?php
ob_start();
include "template_header.php";
?>
<p>Text</p>
<?php
include "template_footer.php";
$message = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

But it doesn't work! `$message` is empty! Even when I do `var_export($message)`, I don't get anything!!! Not even an empty string.

- So what is the problem with my code?
- What are the other ways I can include my text?

Comment: Where are you exporting $message?

Comment: after ob_end_clean(); I have echo "message is: " . var_export($message, true);

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
ob_start(); 
//print all the things - and I mean print. echoing and plain html work.
$message = ob_get_clean();

echo $message;
```